# ChangeNotifierProvider can't seem to get List<String>

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using ChangeNotifierProvider to get a list of strings that i have read from Cloudfirestore. I know that the is okay because i print the legnth of my list to confirm. But somewhere in between the change notifier provider and my UI, I seem to get things lost. Someone help me understand this concept.
Here, i am setting the retrieved list:

```
 class RestorationNetworkService {
  
  static Future<List<String?>> getRepairProducts(RestorationNotifier restNot,) async {
    final firebaseref = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    List<String?> repairproducts = [];

    
    
    final data = await firebaseref.collection("restoration_products").get();
    final datasetMap = data.docs.single.data();
     repairproducts= (datasetMap['product'] as List).map((e) => e as String).toList();
    print(repairproducts.length);
    restNot.restoreProductList = repairproducts;
     
   
   
    return repairproducts;
  }
}
```

Here is my changeNotifier class:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class RestorationNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  List<String?> _repairproducts = [];

  set restoreProductList(List<String?> repairproductlist) {
    _repairproducts= repairproductlist;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<String?> get repairProductList => _repairproducts;
  
}
```

Here i am trying to update my UI with the list:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    //lets load our future right here
    RestorationNetworkService.getRepairProducts(rest);
    super.initState();
  }

 
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    List<String?> restProdList = Provider.of<RestorationNotifier>(context, listen: false).repairProductList;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Restore Furniture')
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Wrap(
                  children: repairChips(restProdList),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
      ),
    );
     
  }

   List<Widget> repairChips(List<String?> restoreProdList) {
    List<Widget> chips = [];
    int selectedIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < restoreProdList.length; i++) {
      Widget item = PhysicalModel(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          color: Colors.transparent,
          shadowColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
          elevation: 10,
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5),
              child: ChoiceChip(
                selected: selectedIndex == i,
                selectedColor: Color(0xFFF7B239),
                label: Text(restoreProdList[i] ?? ''),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2)),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                onSelected: (bool value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = i;
                  });
                },
              )));
      chips.add(item);
    }
    return chips;
  }

}
```

I can't really seem to trace where exactly i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The list you get from Cloudfirestore not set to the state yet.

for current state in your app, the List<String?>  = [ ];

you can modify your init function like below:

```
@override
  void initState() {
   // Fetch the data
   fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

Future<void> fetchData() async {
 final state = context.read<RestorationNotifier>(); // initialize state provider

 final result = await RestorationNetworkService.getRepairProducts(rest);

 state.restoreProductList(result); // you miss this step. that assign the data to state
}

// this is my style using provider.  
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final appState = context.watch<RestorationNetworkService>(); // we watching any change

  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Restore Furniture')
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // then you can access the object here.
                Text('${appState.repairProductList.length}'), //
              ],
            ),
          )),
      ),
    );
}
```